# Excel: labels on a scatter chart, read from array

Tags: excel, charts, label

Here I have a chart

[image]

I did a right-click -> "Add labels" , and it read them from my a(H/C) row. Basically, I want it to read label values from the CO2/CH4 row instead, so they would be 0,0.5,1,2,5,10 instead. Of course, I want the chart itself to remain the same, so, the x values of dots are in row "b(O/C)", their y values are in "a(H/C)" row, and their respective labels are read from "CO2/CH4". Can it be done automatically and how (preferrably, without scripting magic)? Rewriting them manually is a pain, really.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the desired results by following the steps below:
Step 1: Click on the Chart
Step 2: Select the Design Tab in Ribbon Bar (Note: “Design Tab” appears only when the Chart is selected)
Step 3: Click on “Select Data” feature in the Design Tab as shown in Screen Shot 1
Step 4: Click on Edit Button as shown in Screen Shot 2
Step 5: Change the Series Name Rage and  the data range in “Series Y Values:” as highlighted in Screen shot 3
[image: shot1]

[image: shot2]
[image: shot3]

Comment: that's not what I want. I need the chart itself to remain the same, and only the labels to be read from the last row.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the different points as different series and using the series names as labels (instead of the y-values) ?

If you need the "line" between the points (or if you need to add a trendline...), keep the serie you already have (with every point) without labels

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 added the capability to use text from worksheet cells as data point labels. If you don't have 2013 (your screen shot looks like 2010), or even if you do, you can use Rob Bovey's free [Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) add-in